# Context not rendering on template

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

im trying to create a live search using django, AJAX and JQuery, so far i managed to livesearch form my db but when i return the context it doesn't render. However if i use chrome develorper tools, i can see the html in the response with the context properly rendered. I dont know why this is happening, perhaps because im not calling the view correctly

my code looks something like this:

home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<input type="text" id="livesearch" placeholder="Ingresar Usuario Aqui"><br>
{{list_users}}
{% for u in list_users %}
<p>{{u}}</p>
{% endfor %}    
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static "jquery/jquery.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "jquery/plugins/jquery.cookie.js" %}"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#livesearch").on('input', function(e){
            search_text = $("#livesearch").val()
            // console.log(search_text)
            $.ajax({
                method:'post',
                url:'',
                data:{text:search_text},
                beforeSend: function(xhr, settings){
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'));
                },
            })
        })
    })
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

home_view.py

```
def home_view(request):
    searchtext = request.POST.get('text')
    searchtext = str(searchtext).upper()
    print(searchtext)       
    query = '''select NAME from my_base
            where status not in('Disabled', 'Locked')
            and upper(domain_login) LIKE ''' + "'%{}%'".format(searchtext)       
    cursor = method_that_gets_the_cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    users = cursor.fetchall()
    list_users = pd.DataFrame(users)
    context = {
        "list_users": list_users
    }
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from add_users.views import home_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: "Making an ajax request" **!=** "Result automatically replaces the current HTML". You need to put the response sent by the server in the HTML of the page. Plus ideally the url you make the ajax request should be different and the response should only return parts of the page you want to replace.

Comment: Hello, i don't think django can do this without render a piece of the html at least, for example if i want to populate the fields of the html i have to re-render they, at least is the way that i learned.

Comment: You are not using the ajax response at all

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, many thanks for your help. i changed a few things and now works like a charm